# What was wrong with this edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I submitted [this change](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14444485) to a post to fix some formatting, but since I don't have high enough rep, I had to add some fluff words (that did not harm the post in any way) in order to meet the length requirement.

However, after one approval, it was rejected and edited and the note alongside the rejection told me to see what "should have been changed."

Upon checking the new edit, it looks like the changes I'd submitted sans the added character count words were the only changes. That is, the change the other user made seemed to have been *the exact same edit as mine but with less characters*, since they had the privilege to do so.

Was this edit rightfully rejected? It doesn't seem fair to punish a lower-rep user by rejecting an edit solely based on something they're forced to add, especially if it is not harmful to the original post.

Comment: Another time, you could have constructively added additional characters by inserting [syntax highlighting language hints](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109).  For instance adding `<!-- language: lang-python -->`,  prior to the code would have been helpful.

Answer (score 7):

We want to be using edits to *remove* noise, not to *add* noise.  Yes, the edit that you made that adds noise to the post was *rightfully* rejected.

Comment: I can't make an edit like that *without* adding "noise." To reject an edit like that and then proceed to copy the edits that way seems wrong.

Comment: I don't think the additions to meet the character limit would be considered noise if they were in the original edition of the answer so it shouldn't be considered noise in an edit when the editor clearly fixed the things needing fixed.

Comment: The point of this answer @Vemonus, is that you shouldn't force your way in when you don't have the privilege to do otherwise. Adding unnecessary words to meet the length criteria is adding noise. The real problem you have, isn't with the fact that the edit was rejected, but that there is a character limit. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters: *Instead of tricking the rule, just look for other changes that can be made*

Comment: @Vemonus Why does the fact that you couldn't make the correct edit make it okay to make an *incorrect* edit?  Why should someone not make a *correct* edit just because you attempted to apply an *incorrect* edit?  Would you rather the improvement just not be made because if you can't improve it then nobody should be able to?

Comment: @Servy I do not see it as an incorrect edit. The grammatical changes improved readability, in my mind. I understand the SO mantra of keeping things short and sweet, but I don't feel that changing one word to two defeats that purpose.

Comment: @Vemonus Adding noise into a post for the express purpose of adding noise is *not* appropriate.  Again, as an editing you should be *removing* noise from posts, not adding it.

Comment: @Servy I see you won't listen to what I'm saying to that, so I'll change angles. Rejection is one thing. Rejection and editing is another. Rejection implies there were serious problems with the edit and they should all be disregarded. To carbon copy the basis of my edit and call that "what should've been" despite being rejected is harmful in principle. It penalizes me for attempting to help improve the content on the site simply for the reason that I haven't helped enough already to help at all. I'm not seeing how Improve Edit is not the proper course of action here.

Comment: @Vemonus `Rejection implies there were serious problems with the edit` Indeed it does, and there *were* serious problems with your edit.  `and they should all be disregarded` Why does that follow?  The edit had serious problems, and so, it was rejected.  But there was a portion of the edit that *wasn't* harmful, and so that portion was applied.  Why do you think that that good portion shouldn't have been applied just because you also included inappropriate content in your edit that merited it being rejected? There is even an option specifically for this, reject and edit, which was used here.

Comment: @Vemonus You aren't being penalized "for trying to improve the site", you're being penalized *for attempting to make an edit that would have cause harm*.  That you thought you were improving the site by causing said harm makes it *all the more important* to indicate that what you are doing is wrong by rejecting the edit, rather than approving it and giving you the impression that causing said harm is a *good* thing.

Comment: @Servy Firstly, thank you, but I know how editing works. I have reviewed edits outside of SO. That said, Rejection implies there were serious problems, yes. That's carried into Reject + Edit. The rejection comment literally states that my edit failed to address the serious problem with the post. Improve Edit implies "this is helpful, but it could be improved". I'm not seeing how the "Thanks, but let the grown-ups handle it" attitude helps the SO community.

Comment: @Vemonus I agree that the rejection reason isn't ideal.  The rejection reasons are designed to cover the most common cases, and to be short and concise so that they actually get read.  The result of that is that they aren't always as clear in edge cases.  `Improve Edit implies "this is helpful, but it could be improved".`  Indeed.  **Your edit wasn't helpful; your edit was harmful**.  As a result of that, approving it and editing it would not be the correct course of action.

Comment: @Vemonus You seem to be taking this whole thing personally. It shows in your language "doesn't seem fair to punish", "being rejected is harmful", "It penalizes me". You have not been arrested. You have not had your hand slapped. You have not even been sent to your room without supper. You just failed to get two magical unicorn internet points added to your account. Read, learn the lesson, move on.